# From matrices to bipartite graphs

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, graph-theory, inverse

Assume $G(A,B)$ is a bipartite graph and assume $L(G)$ is the adjacency matrix of its line graph. define $$B=[3\text{I}+L(G)]^{-1}$$. Is it always the case that for each edge $e=(a,b)\in G$, we have:

$$B_{e,e}>\sum_{e'\in G, e'=(a,b'),e'\neq e}B_{e,e'}$$

(I have asked the same question in Linear Algebra form here: [Simple to state yet tricky question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/566126/simple-to-state-yet-tricky-question)

Comment: It is fairly easy to show that $B_{e,e}>0$, and experiments suggest that each summand on the right will be negative. Can anyone prove that or give a counterexample?

Comment: By the way, Mathlover, what's your motivation for this question?

Comment: Casteels, I did some computational experiments and it seems each entry of RHS is negative, however the sum of their absolute value is always less than the diagonal entry. So I've edited he problem as well.

Comment: @user107872 you need to add a ``@`` in front of the username to make pinging work. For more info, see here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work

Answer (score 2):

I answered the linear algebra question referenced in this problem. You can read the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/566126/simple-to-state-yet-tricky-question/585551#585551).